# Given $A, A+E$ nonsingular and $Z=(A+E)^{-1}$. Show $||AZ-I||_2\leq ||E||_2||Z||_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $A, A+E$ nonsingular and $Z=(A+E)^{-1}$. Show $||AZ-I||_2\leq ||E||_2||Z||_2$

Attempt at proof: $||AZ-I||_2=||A(A+E)^{-1}-I||_2\leq ||A(A+E)^{-1}||_2+||I||_2$

I'm not sure how to go about this from this point.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\|AZ-I\|_2=\|AZ-(A+E)Z\|_2
$$

Comment: thanks. Obvious from this point